# not comming out of switch case

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm writing a simple program to transfer file from one point to another. The app should present the option
1. list the files
 2. download a file
 3. upload a file
But once I chose option 1. it lists the contents of the directory, I'm sending filenames one by one but but all the names appear in one single line on the client side. Can't figure out why..

And then it's stuck inside the marked loop, it should come out of the loop once the recv is completed and it should present the operation options again. I'm not sure what the problem is.
Here's my code..

## server.c

```
while(1){
  //receive chosen option to be performed 
  if((rdata = recv(clnt, &x, sizeof(int), 0)) > 0){
    opt = ntohl(x);
    switch(opt){ //switch option and operate
    case 1 : //option 1- transfer contents of the directory
      if((dr = opendir(".")) != NULL){
        while((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL){ //open directory
          sprintf(filename, "%s",de->d_name);
          rdata = send(clnt, filename, strlen(filename), 0); //transfer filenames
        }
      }
      break;
    }
```

## client.c

```
    while(1){ //this loop should continue after performing one option
      printf("1. List available files on the server\n");
      printf("2. Download a file\n");
      printf("3. Upload a file to the server\n");
      scanf("%d", &opt); //enter desired option
      x = htonl(opt);  //convert to network byte order
      if(send(sockfd, &x, sizeof(int), 0) < 0){ //send option
        perror("client: send");
        continue;
      }
      switch(opt){
        case 1 :
/************************************************************************/
          while((rdata = recv(sockfd, filename, sizeof(filename), 0)) > 0){
            filename[rdata] = '\0';
            printf("> %s\n", filename);
          }
/***********************************************************************/
          break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At least as I understand you want to loop until the correct operation is executed (in this case 1, 2 or 3). if it is program should exit.

```
int loop = 1;

while(loop){
  loop = 0;
  printf("1. List available files on the server\n");
  printf("2. Download a file\n");
  printf("3. Upload a file to the server\n");
  scanf("%d", &opt);
  x = htonl(opt);
  if(send(sockfd, &x, sizeof(int), 0) < 0){
    perror("client: send");
    continue;
  }
  switch(opt){
    case 1 :
      while((rdata = recv(sockfd, filename, sizeof(filename), 0)) > 0){
        filename[rdata] = '\0';
        printf("> %s\n", filename);
      }
      break;
    default:
      loop = 1;
      break;
  }
}
```

or maybe you want to loop until exit is chosen

```
int loop = 1;

while(loop){
  printf("1. List available files on the server\n");
  printf("2. Download a file\n");
  printf("3. Upload a file to the server\n");
  printf("4. Exir\n");
  scanf("%d", &opt);
  x = htonl(opt);
  if(send(sockfd, &x, sizeof(int), 0) < 0){
    perror("client: send");
    continue;
  }
  switch(opt){
    case 1 :
      while((rdata = recv(sockfd, filename, sizeof(filename), 0)) > 0){
        filename[rdata] = '\0';
        printf("> %s\n", filename);
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      loop = 0;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: It isn't working. The problem is in `while((rdata = recv(sockfd, filename, sizeof(filename), 0)) > 0)` line. When you use `recv()` without loop, it works fine. I guess it's stuck inside the loop

Comment: please edit your answer or remove it.. it's not the exact answer